# Jquery Call to REST self hosted Port number

Tags: jquery, wcf-rest

I just tried to Make a solution on VS 2010 to practice consuming REST services with JQuery.
I used the template WCF REST Service Application. It created a class that I named Services.cs
 with a method that I would like to call:

```
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
    public List<SampleItem> GetCollection()
    {
        SampleItem item;
        List<SampleItem> lst = new List<SampleItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            item = new SampleItem { Prom = 1960 + i, Name = string.Format("Name {0}", i.ToString()) };
            lst.Add(item);
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

the Global.asax.cs looks like:
       void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes();
        }

```
    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        // Edit the base address of Service1 by replacing the "Service1" string below
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service)));
    }
```

Then I made a new asp.net Empty Web Site, added the jquery files etc. In the default.htm page I like to call GetCollection, so I added the following jquery code.

```
    $(function () {
        var serviceUrl = ??????
        $.ajax({
            url: serviceUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: '{}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (colD) {
                var col = colD.d;
            }

        });
    });
```

what URl shoult I put? especially I have hard time to figure out the port on my hostlocal.
I tried http://localhost:5187/KendoRestService/GetCollection, Where KendoRestService is the name of the REST project, and the namespace on service.cs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the port number. Check the properties of the Service Project Alt+Enter, Web Tab, Under Servers check Apply server settings to all users , and Use Visual Studio Development Server, Auto-assign Port. There is a port number in front of Specific port option. This port number will be used by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd want to give [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")] a value i.e [WebGet(UriTemplate = "getCollection")]

Then the javascript url would be:

```
var serviceUrl = ServiceName/UriTemplate
```

so in your case:

```
var serviceUrl = '/getCollection';
```

Comment: No it didn't work. I put a beakpoint to getCollection but it never goes there, nor on success part of ajax call. There are 2 projects in my solution.

Comment: Have you tried changing the parameter typeof(Service) to point to the dll GetCollection() is in?

Comment: Not in the js. Your problem sounds to be related to routing.  What kind of error are you getting from the ajax request? The change is in the global.asax file: RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service)));

Comment: Justin, I added error handling to my ajax call:
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
xhr.status = 0, and thrownError=''; my problem is port number that I don't know where to init. Your solution can't work since my service is located in another project and /getCollection cannot be found. Thanks anyway. Anyone else who has already done jquery to REST WCF?

Comment: Unless your projects are on separate ports it will work. Is your other project building as a separate dll?